# Not able to revoke GAE app from Google account security permissions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My initial version uses the built-in GAE Users Service for application login/registration.

However, I was not able to revoke the app's permissions from my Google account settings.

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Google has updated the dashboard.

I think they missed a feature to allow users to revoke GAE apps permissions.

Can someone help me verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this [1] built-in service, your app have access to the user's email address as well as a unique user ID only while the user is signed into your app. So there is no permanent permissions  to be revoked.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/